# trying to find a formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

There are $n$ animals which need to be put back in a cage.

In a specific 10 minute period each animal will be put back at some random point in time.

Find a formula for the probability that m animals from n is put back at the same time, where the 'same time' means in the same 1 second  interval. The intervals are (0,1),(1,2) etc

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the distribution should be continuous and uniform, which is more difficult than if it is discrete.  If you truly choose from $\{0,\dots,600\}$, there are $601$ choices.  If within 1 second allows some to be placed in at 2 seconds and some at 3 seconds, is also more difficult than if you require them all to be placed at the same exact second.  Please review the problem statement.

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry I wasn't very clear, I meant the same time as in to the nearest second. So doesn't distribution then become effectively discrete

Comment: Yes, if you round all the arrivals to the nearest second and insist they all round to the same number the distribution becomes discrete.  If you use intervals (0-1, 1-2,\dots 599-600) you then have 600 of them.  Your answer is then close, but the exponent should be $n-1$, as the first one can be in any interval, then the remaining $n-1$ have to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you interpret the problem to mean that the $10$-minute interval has been divided up into $600$ one-second intervals (as would happen if you looked at a digital clock), then the probability that all $n$ animals are returned at some point during a *given* one-second interval is $1/600^n$.  Since there are 600 choices for that interval, the answer under this interpretation is $600/600^n = 1/600^{n-1}$.

Comment: If the problem change to m animals from n being put back simultaneously, would the answer be 600*(m C n)*(1/600)^n*(599/600)^m-n ?

Comment: It's more complicated than that.  If $m\le n/2$, for example, you could have $m$ animals put back in multiple time intervals, so depending on the precise question, you'd probably need to use inclusion/exclusion.  In any case, it becomes even more important to state the problem precisely.

Comment: please see my edit of my original post. I have made it clearer I think